# Ensure mutually exclusive interfaces at compile-time?

Tags: c#, attributes, custom-attributes, compile-time

I'd like to ensure that two interfaces are never found on the same class at compile-time, similar to how [AttributeUsage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw5zxet9%28VS.71%29.aspx) checks custom Attributes at compile-time.

e.g.:

```
[InterfaceUsage(MutuallyExclusive = typeof(B))]
interface A {
    //...
}

interface B {
    //...
}

class C : A, B { //should throw an error on compile time
    //...
}
```

I can obviously do this at runtime with reflection, but I'm interested in a compile-time solution.

I'd imagine that one probably doesn't exist out of the box - but is there a way to create a custom attribute that is run at compile-time, much like AttributeUsage is?

Comment: Not with just the regular C# compiler...

Comment: You could build an FxCop rule.

Comment: Curious to understand the use case that require mutually exclusive interfaces...

Comment: @Rowland Shaw e.g. ICat and IDog shouldn't be found on the same class.  Downstream users of my library might not understand that their animal can't be a hybrid CatDog, so I'd like to insert a rule that checks this for them.

Comment: Is it possible to use abstract classes instead of interfaces?

Comment: @Mike Two - good idea, that would work for most cases.  Unfortunately I've a couple of classes which already inherit from another class.

Comment: @sprocketonline - Haven't you heard about the new hybrid Dog-cat that was born in a lab?

Comment: I would consider rethinking your object model, i.e. using composition instead of inheritance.  If something can't be both an ICat and an IDog, then those shouldn't be interfaces.

Comment: You'll likely get diminishing returns from a compile time solution. The .Net Framework makes no attempt to stop a user from making illogical interface implementation choices and neither should you! If it is absolutely necessary a few run-time checks are ok, but really, if a user wants to go out of their way to implement something silly (e.g. the hypothetical `IQueue`, `IStack`, and `IDictionary` all the while deriving from `LinkedList`) you should probably let them.

Comment: @sprocketonline I know what you mean by mutually exclusive - I just don't understand the use case that *requires* it.

Comment: I think we're collectively having difficulty understanding why you might want to do this - any chance you can be a bit more explicit about what your *actual* interfaces are, so that we can see why it doesn't make sense for a class to implement both?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A different approach could be to change them to Abstract classes.

Answer (score 2):

How about giving them two methods with identical signatures, but incompatible return types?

Comment: I would consider this more of a warning since they can explicitly implement one of the interfaces. Although I'm pretty sure you can't do much better without an external tool.

Answer (score 0):

A "workaround" would be to just add /// to both interfaces warning that they shouldn't be used together, because of such and such reason. It's addressing a pitfall with a caution sign, but it's better than nothing.

I ran into a similar case: Local and Global conditions. One can only depend on a fixed portion of the array around a position, while the other cannot depend on position at all. Put both together and you have a useless condition.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be 100% of the way there, but you can obtain *some* errors at compile-time for interfaces that you want to be mutually-exclusive. Assuming we want to disallow people from implementing both of the interfaces `cat` and `dog` on the same class:

```
interface cat_or_dog
{
    bool IsCute { get; }
}

interface cat_or_dog<A> : cat_or_dog where A : cat_or_dog
{
    A Self { get; }
}

interface cat : cat_or_dog<cat>
{
    Guid Meow { get; }
};

interface dog : cat_or_dog<dog>
{
    Single Woof { get; }
};
```

With this setup, you will get actually get a fatal compile error if a class tries to implement both of the mutually exclusive interfaces publically, as shown in `demo3` and `demo4`. It's caused by a `Type` collision on the return-value of a member in the shared base class `cat_or_dog<A>`:

```
class demo1 : cat         // ok
{
    public bool IsCute => true;
    public cat Self => this;
    public Guid Meow => Guid.NewGuid();
};

class demo2 : dog         // ok
{
    public bool IsCute => true;
    public dog Self => this;
    public Single Woof => 10.0f;
};

class demo3 : cat, dog // CS0535: "doesn't implement 'dog.Woof' and 'cat_or_dog<dog>.Self'
{
    public bool IsCute => default;
    public cat Self => this;
    public Guid Meow => Guid.NewGuid();
};

class demo4 : dog, cat // CS0535: "doesn't implement 'cat.Meow' and 'cat_or_dog<cat>.Self'
{
    public bool IsCute => default;
    public dog Self => this;
    public Single Woof => 10.0f;
};
```

(The `Meow` and `Woof` errors are caused when the automatic interface implementation feature of the IDE not completing the refactoring after the more serious error, for some reason)

[image]

As you surely know however, this is a variation of the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), so it is still possible to "incorrectly" implement both interfaces by using C# [explicit interface implementation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/explicit-interface-implementation):

```
class demo5 : dog, cat         // ok
{
    public bool IsCute => true;

    cat cat_or_dog<cat>.Self => this;
    Guid cat.Meow => throw null;

    dog cat_or_dog<dog>.Self => this;
    float dog.Woof => 10.0f;
};
```